# Upload using mime/multipart corrupts the file

Tags: http, go

I wrote a server that has a route to upload a picture. This is a form that receive a few parameters: `title`, `description`, `visibility` and the `picture`. The page also uses the `Authentication` header.

```
func UploadPictureRoute(prv *services.Provider) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        user, err := auth.ValidateRequest(prv, w, r)
        if auth.RespondError(w, err) {
            return
        }

        r.ParseMultipartForm(10 << 20) // 10 meg max

        title := r.FormValue("title")
        desc := r.FormValue("description")
        visib := r.FormValue("visibility")
        visibInt, err := strconv.Atoi(visib)
        visibility := int8(visibInt) // Visibility can be either 0, 1, 2

        if err != nil {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        }

        file, _, err := r.FormFile("picture")
        if err != nil {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }
        defer file.Close()

        mimeType, _, err := mimetype.DetectReader(file) // Package gabriel-vasile/mimetype
        if err != nil {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }

        if !utils.IsValidMimetype(mimeType) { // Basically just comparing to image/png, image/jpg. Crashes here
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }

        parentFolder := prv.PicturePath + "/" + strconv.FormatInt(*user.ID, 10) + "/"

        _, err = os.Stat(parentFolder)
        if os.IsNotExist(err) {
            err = os.MkdirAll(parentFolder, os.ModePerm)
            if err != nil {
                w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
                return
            }
        }

        pict := model.Picture{
            Title:       title,
            Description: desc,
            Creator:     &user,
            Visibility:  visibility,
            Ext:         utils.GetExtForMimetype(mimeType),
        }

        pict, err = dal.CreatePicture(prv, pict)
        if err != nil {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }

        outputFile, err := os.Create(parentFolder + strconv.FormatInt(*pict.ID, 10) + "." + pict.Ext)
        if err != nil {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
            dal.DeletePicture(prv, pict)
        }
        defer outputFile.Close()

        _, err = io.Copy(outputFile, file)
        if err != nil {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
// Responding 
    }
}
```

This works well using `Postman`, it uploads the file correctly and everything works as expected.

However, i failed to write a go `http` client to upload a file:

```
type uploadResponse struct {
    URLID string
}

func main() {
    filename := "filename.png"

    file, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    // Just to be sure we're really at the start of the file
    _, err = file.Seek(0, io.SeekStart)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Can't read the file")
        return
    }

    mime, _, err := mimetype.DetectReader(file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Can't read the file")
        return
    }

    if !api.IsMimetypeAllowed(mime) { // Just check if it's a jpg/png/gif. This works on the client
        fmt.Println("This filetype can't be uploaded to a Scinna server.")
        fmt.Println("Please convert this file to jpeg, png or gif.")

        return
    }


    body := &bytes.Buffer{}
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)

    title, _ := writer.CreateFormField("title")
    title.Write([]byte("My picture title"))

    desc, _ := writer.CreateFormField("description")
    desc.Write([]byte("My picture description"))

    visib, _ := writer.CreateFormField("visibility")
    visib.Write([]byte("0"))

    pict, _ := writer.CreateFormFile("picture", file.Name())
    _, err = io.Copy(pict, file)

    writer.Close()

    r, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://myapi.local/pictures", body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    r.Header.Add("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())
    r.Header.Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+config.Token)

    client := &http.Client{}
    client.Do(r)
}
```

This code makes the server crash. The mimetype of the picture becomes `application/octet-stream` and the image headers are broken (It still opens in some editors, but EyesOfGnome basically says that the picture is not a JPG/PNG file because it can't find the magic numbers at the beginning)

How do i fix the HTTP go client to successfully upload pictures ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `mimetype.DetectReader(file)` reads part of the file.  The call to  `_, err = io.Copy(pict, file)` reads the remainder of the file. To read the entire file, seek back to offset 0 before the call to `io.Copy`.

Files are opened at offset 0. There's no need to seek to offset 0  immediately after the call to `Open`.

Fix the problem by swapping order of the calls:

```
...

mime, _, err := mimetype.DetectReader(file)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Can't read the file")
    return
}

// Rewind to the start of the file
_, err = file.Seek(0, io.SeekStart)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Can't read the file")
    return
}

...
```

The sever has a similar problem.  Rewind after detecting the type:

```
mimeType, _, err := mimetype.DetectReader(file) // Package gabriel-vasile/mimetype
if err != nil {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}

// Rewind to the start of the file
_, err = file.Seek(0, io.SeekStart)
if err != nil {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}
```

Comment: The picture is correctly detected as an image now but it still is corrupted once uploaded (Same issue in eyes of gnome)

Comment: Oh yeah, that was obvious. Thanks. Any clue on why was it working in postman though?

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution:

[UploadFile](https://github.com/GoesToEleven/golang-web-dev/tree/master/034_photo-blog/04_upload-pictures)

Clone this, if you find any problem, comment here.

Comment: you have to explain the authors problem and its solution using your words. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer